# The Product Topology

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ be infinite sets, let $t$ be the discrete topology on $X$ and let $u$ be the trivial topology on $Y$.  Describe the product topology on $X \times Y$.  This is a book problem and I was hoping to get some insight.  What do they want?  "Describe" seems very vague and I just don't know where to start.

Comment: You could try to characterize all the open sets in $X×Y$.

Comment: Usually "describe" here means "tell me how to determine if a set is open in this topology."

Comment: Would describing the basis, B= (UxV: U is in u and V is in t) and then saying the product of an infinite set and a discrete set is infinite and open, suffice?

Answer (score 4):

**Answer.** Let $\tau$ be the topology of the product space $X\times Y$, then 
$$
\tau=\big\{A\times Y: A\in\mathscr P(X)\big\}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

A book answer would be to write down the topology itself on $X\times Y$, i.e. the set of open subsets.

Now, as $Y$ has the trivial topology, that is, any point of $y$ have only one neighborhood (the whole space), and I like to imagine that so that all the points are 'very close' to each other, pressed together in one inseparable entity.

The product topology can be visualized as when we replace every point $x$ of $X$ to the pressed space $Y$.

Answer (score 0):

Describe the product topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $X\times Y$. Let $\mathcal{T}$ be the collection of all unions of sets as
$$
\mathcal{U}=\big\{U_X\times U_Y: U_X\in\mathcal{T}_X,\ U_Y\in\mathcal{T}_Y\big\}
$$
where $\mathcal{T}_X=\mathscr{P}(X)$ and $\mathcal{T}_Y=\big\{\emptyset ,Y\big\}$.

You can think about  it as as cartesian product $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ wher you have total freedom to chose your points on one axis but you have no idea where you are on the other one (makes sense?).

Comment: You shouldn't have $\{\}$ around $\mathcal P(X)$ and your second $\tau_X$ should be $\tau_Y$